# Variance from T to object with generic constraints object vs class

Tags: c#, generics

Was trying to figure out how I could cast from `Converter<string, T>` to `Converter<string, object>` when I had the constraint `where T : object`. Solved it by changing the constraint to `where T : class`, but I'm not entirely sure why this worked.

This does not compile:

```
public void Foo<T>(Converter<string, T> x) where T : object
{
    Converter<string, object> y = x;
}

Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Converter<string,T>' to 'System.Converter<string,object>'
```

Yet the following does, why is this?

```
public void Foo<T>(Converter<string, T> x) where T : class
{
    Converter<string, object> y = x;
}
```

Comment: `object` is more generic than `class`. `object` includes all object types, including boxed value types. `class` restricts it to just reference types. Not sure `object` as a constraint really means anything, as it essentially means you'd be constraining it 'but not *really*!'

Comment: @Magus a boxed value type *would* meet the `class` constraint.  There isn't anything that meets the `object` constraint that doesn't also meet the `class` constraint.

Comment: @Servy: Except, perhaps, being valid syntax. If it was valid, a value type would simply be autoboxed, whereas the class constraint specifically restricts it.

Comment: @Magus It's ambiguous what an `object` constraint would actually mean, which is the *reason* it's prohibited.  It could automatically box any value types, as you describe; in this case such a constraint probably should have just been omitted entirely.  It could mean that the value type would need to have already been boxed before it can be passed in (in which case, it would function identically to the `class` constraint).  The later option is the only one ever worth using, but as it's ambiguous what it would mean, they added the special keyword `class` to use instead, specifically for clarity.

Comment: @Servy: Exactly my point, but rather at odds with your previous point. Clearly, as `object` is ambiguous and `class` isn't, you can't say they directly map.

Comment: @Magus Well, you also can't say they *don't* map, given that it's not legal in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such generic constraint as `: object`. The first example has two errors:

> Error  1   Constraint cannot be special class 'object'

and then:

> Error  2   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Converter' to 'System.Converter'

so what is simply saying that because of no valid constraint, cast from not constraint `System.Converter<string,T>` cannot be done to `Converter<string, object>`.

The second example has a valid contraint. `T` is reference type and can be casted to `object` as it is the root of the type hierarchy.

Comment: True, not sure how I didn't spot that other error :p thanks, will accept when I can